# clang Can't find any frameworks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I've been tearing my hair out over this, and Google hasn't yielded much so my problem must be caused by my own specific brand of stupidity.

Basically, having installed Xcode 4 I removed the /Developer-old folder (properly, can't remember the command but I used the uninstall script rather than sticking it in the trash).

Xcode builds projects fine, and the latest version of all the Objective-C frameworks seem to live in /System/Library/Frameworks, but when I compile something (which built fine in the Xcode 3 days) clang complains that it can't find any headers, e.g:

`fatal error: 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found`

I've tried forcing the framework search path with `-F` to no avail- is there a common underlying issue or have I just screwed my machine?

Comment: I don't have Xcode 4, but this typically depends on what SDK you're using; unless you're building against the current OS then the headers it uses are in /Developer/SDKs/....  Maybe you're trying to use a SDK that is either not supported in Xcode 4 or is not installed?

Comment: Just reinstalled it, and clang, gcc, g++ and the rest of the toolchain has reappeared in my path. The installer from the app store doesn't fail very gracefully but if you get the contents and run the package underneath, you get an old-style installer. I dropped the iPhone SDK which saved me 8GB as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall the developer tools.  It will take a lot less time than tracking down whatever you broke.

Comment: Will do this tomorrow. You're probably right, I just hate sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut solutions ;)